# How can I set up a shared e-mail address on Google Apps?

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email

I want to set up an e-mail address in Google Apps for Business that multiple users can use,
for example: `the_team@mycompany.com`.

How do I do this so 2 or more users can access, read and send e-mails from this account?

Answer (score 4):

There are (at least) two ways to share a Gmail account.

1. Set up Mail Delegation (example: share with an assistant)
   https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350?hl=en
2. Create a Shared Inbox using Google Groups (example: several people process / manage help email address):
   https://support.google.com/a/answer/167430?hl=en

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check out Gmelius: https://gmelius.com/.

You can share the entire inbox for the_team@mycompany.com. This way all your team members will be able to manage incoming emails to the_team@ directly from their personal inboxes.

You can also share Gmail labels with only certain colleagues.

Once a shared inbox/label is created, your team will be able to collaboratively manage emails:

1. Exchange internal notes on the side of an email conversation
2. Assign emails to each other for clear accountability
3. Treat your inbox as a help desk and your emails as tasks, adding statuses like open/pending/closed
4. Avoid double replies or unanswered emails by seeing when somebody is viewing or replying to an email
5. Create and share email template for consistent brand voice as well as automated flows based on your recipients' interactions

Answer (score -1):

Since my orginal question is marked as a duplicate of this one, I am presenting my somewhat different answer here:

The following ways can be use:

1. Mail delegation.
2. Shared inbox.

Mail delegation shows the message read if either party reads the message.  I looked at this situation, but found that it wasn't want I wanted.  Threads in my business can run for months.  To be sure both parties have kept up, it's necessary to for one party to consistently mark unread after reading.  This is clunky.

3. Filters.

This is the only acceptable answer I've found to date.

This is an interim answer.  My real situation is somewhat more complicated with multiple incoming addresses.  I *think* that this is a working solution.

A: myBusiness@gmail.com forwards all incoming email to user1@gmail.com.  Keep copy in inbox is also checked. (Settings -> Forwarding and Pop tab)

B: myBusiness also sets up a filter that forwards all mail from:myBusiness@gmail.com to user1@gmail.com

C: User1 adds myBusiness as an responding address (Accounts & Import tab) and checks, "Reply with the same address as the message was sent to"

D: User1 adds a filter that searches for From: myBusiness@gmail.com, and forwards a copy of that to myBusiness@gmail.com  This may not be right.

(Not sure how gmail prevents this from looping but it seems to work.

Analysis:

Message replying to an ad comes to myBusiness.  On incoming, a copy is forwarded to user1. (A)

The person using the main account responds to it. The From: filter forwards a copy to user1. (B)

User1 responds to a message.  It came in from myBusiness so that address is used for the reply. (C)